# регулярные выражения: найти одинаковое кол-во символов (порядок произвольный)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, поиск, подстрока

подскажите каким регулярным выражением можно найти следующу подстроку

```
0<1 и 2 d в произвольном подядке, но кол-во 1 и 2 должно быть одинаковым>0
```

например в строке

```
70011212208012209022211101
```

должно быть найдено

```
01121220
02221110
```

а вот

```
01220
```

должно быть проигнарировано потому что 2ек больше 1

Comment: Обязательно это делать регуляркой?

Comment: не обязательно, но приятно было бы сделать это в 1 строку

Comment: Регулярным выражением этого не сделать. Пишите автомат со счётчиком.

Comment: Любое вычисление на Питон можно записать в одну строку. Но не всегда будет приятно. В данном случае простой цикл лучше.

Comment: `00` забыли в примере.

Comment: жаль, почему-то думал, что регулярка более гибкая

Comment: Язык регулярных выражений не имеет памяти. Как только вы пишите что надо сравнить два счётчика символов, вы требуете память/состояние. А её нет, только позиция в строке и позиция в выражении. Можно почитать теорию, там доходчиво объясняют как глядя на требования определить подходит к ним регулярка или нет.

Comment: как вариант можно перечислить все варианты вхождений `(12, 21) ^++ (1122, 1212, 2121)`.... и потом их искать. разумеется ни о какой красоте кода речи не идет, но это хотя бы реализуемо :3

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не совместить?

```
import re

text = '70011212208012209022211101'
for t in re.findall(r'(?<=0)[12]*(?=0)', text):
    print(f'{("" if t.count("1") == t.count("2") else "не ")}подходит: 0{t}0')
```

```
подходит: 00
подходит: 01121220
не подходит: 01220
подходит: 02221110
```

Answer (score 1):

Регулярным выражением этого не сделать.

```py
def search(s):
    i = s.find('0')
    while i != -1:
        j = s.find('0', i + 1)
        if j != -1:
            c1 = s.count('1', i + 1, j)
            c2 = s.count('2', i + 1, j)
            if c1 == c2 and c1 + c2 == j - (i + 1):
                yield s[i:j + 1]
        i = j


print(*search('70011212208012209022211101'))
```

> ```
> 00 01121220 02221110
> ```